# Web.config URL Rewrite specific match URL

Tags: url-rewriting, web-config

I have the following web.config URL Rewrite rule:

```
<rule name="RedirectUserFriendlyURL1" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^propertysearch\.asp$" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_METHOD}" pattern="^POST$" negate="true" />
        <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="^urlrewrite=([^=&amp;]+)$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="{C:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
<rule name="RewriteUserFriendlyURL1" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^([^/]+)/?$" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="propertysearch.asp?urlrewrite={R:1}" />
</rule>
```

The problem is it is applying this to everything so what I want to do is change the match url syntax to tell it to ONLY run when "-to-rent-in-" is included in the URL, so...

www.domain.com/villas-to-rent-in-florida

WILL qualify and have the rule applied, BUT this wouldn't

www.domain.com/testentry

I have tried different variants but it keeps hitting an error :(

Comment: Can `-to-rent-in-` be anywhere in the url or only before the first `/`?

Comment: Thanks for getting back. Only before the first /. Essentially the URL's will always look like this: www.domain.com/[property type]-to-rent-in-[location] so www.domain.com/villas-to-rent-in-florida, www.domain.com/apartments-to-rent-in-new-york, etc. Hope that helps :)

Comment: I won't be able to test the answer I just posted before Monday so if it doesn't work, don't hesitate to comment!

Comment: Hi there, thank you so much for this :). Sadly it doesn't quite work, when I visit one of the url's it delivers a page not found at the mo... so sorryyy - really appreciate the help.

Comment: Can you try to change `rewrite` to `redirect` just as a test to see where the rule takes you?

Comment: Thanks, I gave that a try and it just seems to stay on the same URL... Not sure if that has helped you or not :|

Comment: Not sure but try to change \w to +*  in the pattern

Comment: Sadly that hit a Web.Config error, BUT I have been messing around with it more and more, and... I THINK I have got it working by using: <match url="^([a-z-]+-to-rent-in-[a-z-]+)/?$" /> Would this look good to you? (Complete guess work with mixing bits I know, your help, etc. BUT seems to be working??). Thanks again :)

Comment: You should use [a-Z] (remove the last -) in this case but I will get back to your question on Monday and will edit my answer with the solution I think should be the best for your case :)

Comment: Right, I changed it to <match url="^([a-Z]+-to-rent-in-[a-Z]+)/?$" /> but now I sadly get this error: "The expression "^([a-Z]+-to-rent-in-[a-Z]+)/?$" contains a character range specifier that is not valid." So, for now I have just changed it back to what I had, then that would be really excellent if you could take a look on Monday as I do love knowing how to do it in the best way possible :). Thanks again.

Comment: I have updated my answer and it should now cover all your cases. If not, let me know :)

Comment: That's working perfectly, and thank you for doing that for me. Very much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the url to trigger the rewrite only when `-to-rent-in-` is part of the first portion of the url, you could use:

```
<rule name="RewriteUserFriendlyURL1" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^(.+-to-rent-in-.+)/?$" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="propertysearch.asp?urlrewrite={R:1}" />
</rule>
```

`url="^(.+-to-rent-in-.+)/?$"` will match any url containing at least one character before `-to-rent-in-` and at least one after.

You don't want to limit the character(s) before or after to be only alphanumeric since your url can be like: `www.domain.com/apartments-to-rent-in-new-york` (where `new-york` contains a `-`)